# Spring Boot 2 Actuator Config Property Sources Not Found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config, spring-boot-2

I've been trying to migrate from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.4.2.
I have a problem with /health endpoint of actuator which says:

```
"clientConfigServer": {
  "status": "UNKNOWN",
  "details": {
    "error": "no property sources located"
  }
}
```

in active profile native. For older version everything worked as expected and I was receiving:

```
"configServer": {
  "status": "UP",
  "propertySources": [
     "file:C:\\Users\user\projects\tagging.yml",
  ]
}
```

Is this a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: are you using `spring.profiles`? if so, they don't work in 2.4.2, the property is now called `spring.config.activate.on-profile`. Take a look at
https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

Comment: This is not the case... I use the `spring.config.activate.on-profile` but it doesn't matter here.

Comment: I also get "status": "UNKNOWN", even though the config server is working. I tried changing a few settings, but couldn't get anything to work. The spring code appears to be looking for a propertysource called configClient in ConfigServerHealthIndicator.  I don't have a configClient property source in the list, but I do have a bootstrapProperties-configClient, which is a configClient property source wrapped in a bootstrapPropertySource.